# Build a PKCS#15 file from ASN.1 syntax

Tags: c++, pki, asn.1, pkcs#12, pkcs#15

I'm trying to build a pkcs#15 file to store certificate and the key pair that their data are extracted from a PKCS#12 file and I really don't know where to start. I have already read the [pkcs15 structure](ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-15/pkcs15v1.doc) written by asn.1 syntax. Is there anyone who have experience in this field that could help me?

UPDATE#1: After awhile, I have successful create a pkcs#15 file from PKCS12 file or .pem file by using the tools call pemtrans with the support of openssl and cryptlib.
Now I'm finding way to parse the info from this pkcs#15 for further use.

Comment: Are you using any language? or are you asking about for a specific tool?

Comment: @albciff i'm using C++ for my project, i have already tried ASN1C but their are too many errors due to the lack of some module library.

Comment: @TienLe my experience with asn1 and PKCS#15 are with java and bouncycastle, unfortunately I don't know how can achieve it with c++.

Comment: @albciff Java is fine for me. Could you show me the way to achieve this through java? Thank you!

Comment: @TienLe I only use `PKCS#15` to "wrap" `PKCS#11` devices, anyway if you are looking for a way to represent `PKCS#15` ASN1 structure defined in the document which you refer in your question, take a look on Opensc-java project (use BC for ASN1) : https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC-Java. More exactly the ASN1 structures of `PKCS#15`: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC-Java/tree/master/pkcs15/src/main/java/org/opensc/pkcs15/asn1.

Comment: @albciff thank you but i'm trying to develop a software token, which means without the smartcard. Unfortunately, OpenSC in C++ needs a smart card to init a .p15 structure. But maybe OpenSC-Java will be different, I'll study it.